# Jboss AS 6 define XA and Local datasource using tnsnames.ora

Tags: java, oracle, jboss

I have installed Oracle Instant client for accessing database servers. I need to do this. because there are 2 databases which switchover. So I wanted to use TNS server name to access active database server.  I have installed OCI and define necessary environment variables using following manual

http://www.interfaceware.com/manual/oracle_instant_client.html

Then I tested my conenction using ODBC Data Source Administrator. When I press "Test Connection" , I can easily connect servers defined in TNSNames. ora.

[image]

Here you can find my TNSNames.ora definition

```
DSA =
 (DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ip1)(PORT=1526))
  (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ip2)(PORT=1526))
)
(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=dsa)
(SERVICE_NAME = DSA)))
```

Now I need to define XA and local datasource.  I can use url-delimiter for local datasource. But I need to use tns name in my datasource definition for XA datasource.

Local Data Source definition

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
<jndi-name>SiguardDsaDS</jndi-name>
<connection-url>jdbc:oracle:oci11:@DSA</connection-url>
 <url-delimiter>|</url-delimiter>
<driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>

<max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
<!-- Uses the pingDatabase method to check a connection is still valid before handing it out from the pool -->
<!--valid-connection-checker-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name-->
<!-- Checks the Oracle error codes and messages for fatal errors -->
<exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
    <!-- sql to call when connection is created
    <new-connection-sql>some arbitrary sql</new-connection-sql>
    -->

    <!-- sql to call on an existing pooled connection when it is obtained from pool - the OracleValidConnectionChecker is prefered
    <check-valid-connection-sql>some arbitrary sql</check-valid-connection-sql>
    -->

  <!-- corresponding type-mapping in the standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml (optional) -->
  <metadata>
     <type-mapping>Oracle9i</type-mapping>
  </metadata>
```

This is XA Datasource definition ( too critical for me)

```
<datasources>
 <xa-datasource>
<jndi-name>QuartzDS</jndi-name>

<xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
<xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:oracle:oci11:@DSA</xa-datasource-property>
<url-delimiter>|</url-delimiter>
<transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
<max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
<min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>

<blocking-timeout-millis>2000</blocking-timeout-millis>
<idle-timeout-minutes>2</idle-timeout-minutes>
<track-connection-by-tx>true</track-connection-by-tx>
 <no-tx-separate-pools>false</no-tx-separate-pools>


  <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>

   </xa-datasource>

   </datasources>
```

I am getting exception

```
16:40:20,689 WARN  [SettingsFactory] Could not obtain connection to query metadata: org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Unable to get managed connection for SiguardDsaDS; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for SiguardDsaDS)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:95) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:71) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:114) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2833) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2829) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:902) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.jboss.jpa.builder.DefaultCEMFBuilder.build(DefaultCEMFBuilder.java:47) [:1.0.2-alpha-3]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.scanner.HackCEMFBuilder.build(HackCEMFBuilder.java:49) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitDeployment.start(PersistenceUnitDeployment.java:275) [:1.0.2-alpha-3]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_30]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_30]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_30]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:257) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:125) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:72) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:202) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:894) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:641) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:182) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:58) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_30]
  Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Unable to get managed connection for SiguardDsaDS
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:441) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:414) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:496) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2$ConnectionManagerProxy.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:941) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:89) [:6.0.0.Final]
... 84 more
 Caused by: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection using any of the URLs: [jdbc:oracle:oci11:@DSA]
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getHALocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:311) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:211) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:648) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:272) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:690) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:403) [:6.0.0.Final]
... 88 more
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: Did you create a tnsnames.ora file in the directory where the client instance was installed?

Comment: Yes. I have put it C:\Oracle\instantclient_11_1. My TNS_ADMIN environment variable is set to this location. If I could not configure it correctly, I think I willl not be able connect via Oracle Datasource Administrator Tool

Comment: It is necessary to choose how to connect to the database by the name of the service or SID database.
Two different records of database aliases in tnsnames..ora

`DSA =
 (DESCRIPTION=
 (ADDRESS_LIST =
   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ip1)(PORT=1526))
   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ip2)(PORT=1526))
 )
 (CONNECT_DATA=
  (SID=dsa)
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)

)`

or 

`DSA2 =
 (DESCRIPTION=
 (ADDRESS_LIST =
   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ip1)(PORT=1526))
   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ip2)(PORT=1526))
 )
 (CONNECT_DATA=
 (SERVICE_NAME = DSA)
 (SERVER = DEDICATED)
)`

Comment: So should I just add  (SERVER = DEDICATED)?

Comment: no, it's not necessary.

Comment: So you tell me that service_name and sid should not be together. This did not change anything. Still it does not work